# Round Robin Seeding simple logic iteration psudocode required

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going bananas at something that should be simple. A teamfixtures table for a league database. Imagine we have 12 teams with primary key 1,2,3... until 12 in team table

Each team plays each other twice home and away. Imagine that team fixtures is empty but I want to loop 22 (total weeks of league with 12 teams) times with an inner loop of 6 times (since 6 days games a week)

The idea is to make it so that (as much as possible) each team gets home game then and away game

So the table we want to populate is team fixtures with a hometeamId and an AwayTeamId (remembering 1-12 for each team))

How can we loop in c sharp and have it seed 1st half of season everyone plays everyone once. Then the 2nd half repeating but reversed

I keep getting into a mess with the logic and the examples online explain the pricinples of round robin seeding but no good simple examples

Trying now to rotate them clockwise I think thats the way to go, should be easy but its tricky

REgards

J

Comment: Are you wanting to include dates in the table as well?

Comment: Hi, the dates I can sort, i'm getting in a flux with the basic logic to loop and do a round robin...

i.e. week 1
H v A
1 v 2
3 v 4
5 v 6...etc then loop and have it fair so that a home team next week would be away and so on (although perhaps thats not wholly possible need it to be like that as much as pobssible)

Comment: All about the matching row by row of Home and Away so they only meet once in the 1st half but they are split evenly home then away etc

Comment: Ended up just using an online generator where I specified the team names as 1-12 then pasted the results into Excel then created insert statements in Excel. 10 minutes and tables are Seeded - looks good. When have more time perhaps will code it up next year